# Mysql database made scolling get stuck

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm building a website and started with this scrolling system, then I added a mysql database but when I get to the pages where he has to scroll it jams. I inspected the element an I can see there are errors but I don't know how to fix them, im very desperate and hopefully someone knows how to fix this problem. The page where the scrolling jammed is: http://catalogusdertoeval.nl/woord.php?id=351 at least that is one of the pages but it is all the same problem on the other pages.

Comment: What are the errors? I don't think MySQL is too blame on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this should guide you a bit. I did two things but you'll have to figure the rest it.

**1. Checked out the errors that are created:**

[image]

**2. Then I did a quick google search since I don't use jQuery that often.**

[image]

I'm thinking the browser stopped executing your javascript because of errors in your code. I don't MySQL has anything to do with it.

**Note:**
I did not go through your code.